# Таблица из БД выполнена в виде ассоциации в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

Использую подход DataBase First. В БД, в которой храниться информация о приемах в больнице, есть три таблицы: Visit(информация о приеме пациента, в том числе id приема), Analysis(id и name конкретного вида анализов) и Visit_Analysis(сопоставляется id приема и id анализа для определения какие анализы были назначены на каких приемах).

При создании модели из БД в ней получаются две таблицы Visit и Analysis, а таблица Visit_Analysis выполнена в виде ассоциации с именем Visit_Analysis.

Вопрос в том, можно ли из кода программы выполнить запрос в БД **средствами EntityFramework** на добавление записей или чтение из таблицы Visit_Analysis? т.к. в классе DbContext нет сущности Visit_Analysis.

Comment: В ентити у Вас должно получиться что-то типа такого `class Vist { ... List<Analysis> analysises ... }` и/или `class Analysis { ... Visit visit ... }` И этого оказывается достаточно. Visit_Analysis обрабатывается ентитем фреймвёрком вместо Вас.

Comment: Все так, в классе Visit есть поле ICollection<Analysis>. А как мне заполнить эту коллекцию?

Comment: Я делаю запрос к таблице Analysis для получения множества объектов Analysis, названия которых были выбраны пользователем в форме и получаю IQuaryable<Analysis>. Привести IQuaryable<Analysis> к ICollection<Analysis> не получается, а при попытке обратиться по-элементно к IQuaryable<Analysis>, чтобы каждый элемент добавить к ICollection<Analysis> не удается, т.к. возникает ошибка:  Тип узла "ArrayIndex" выражения LINQ не поддерживается в LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Как Вы по-элементно выбираете Analysis из IQuaryable<Analysis>, что в результате вместо элемента типа Analysis получаете элемент типа ArrayIndex?

Comment: с помощью foreach

Comment: Разобрался, сам ошибся. Я делал запрос, результатом которого должна являться одна запись (анализ, имя которого совпадает с одним из отмеченных в форме). Потом, не придумав ничего лучше, использовал foreach, чтобы извлечь значения атрибутов этой записи. Тогда и появлялась ошибка. foreach работает, когда результатом запроса является множество записей, соответствующих отмеченным анализам.